# Using Node during asset compilation rails on heroku

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, heroku

Does anybody know if this issue of old node versions regarding using https://github.com/dockyard/es6_module_transpiler-rails on Heroku has been resolved.

https://gist.github.com/bcardarella/7384208

> Copying the gist:
>
> I have been working with Peter Wagenet from Tilde on getting support
>   for Ember Appkit on Heroku with a Rails app. First some background:
>
> Ember Appkit will Transpile ES6 modules for use as AMDs. To that end I
>   wrote the es6_module_transpiler-rails gem which uses Node and Square's
>   es6-module-transpiler package. That package makes use of Esprima for
>   the parsing. There is an issue of a reserved keyword in older
>   JavaScript runtimes not being quoted properly:
>   https://code.google.com/p/esprima/issues/detail?id=469
>
> On our local machines everything works OK and the transpiling does not
>   bomb out because our versions of Node are recent. However, when we
>   deploy to Heroku and Rails attempts to pre-compile its assets the
>   version of Node that Heroku uses is out of date. Based upon some
>   research it appears by default Heroku is using Node v0.4.7 which is
>   from April 2011. It is easy enough to force Heroku to use a more up to
>   date version of Node:
>   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#versions however
>   it is currently unclear if this will run side-by-side with a Rails app
>   for pre-compilation. Furthermore, I do not think it is reasonable to
>   ask Rails developers to include Node configuration code for Heroku in
>   the apps.
>
> I respectfully request that the default version of Node for Rails's
>   asset compilation get bumped up to a more recent version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we support integration through node by using multi buildpack and by defining a `package.json` in your application. Here's the PR https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/pull/245

Make sure nodejs comes first in the .buildpacks file then you can get any version of Node you want.